# Sign windows application

Tags: c#, windows, certificate, ssl-certificate, sign

I have an SSL X.509-certificate, which is issued for me and signed by an official CA *(Certification Authority)*.

I know, that VS allows to sign your .NET-Assemblies with a given certificate. Will this remove the Windows `The publisher of this Application could not be verified`-message when someone executes my signed application?

And if this is not the case, what must I do to the remove the message mentioned above?

Comment: When you say 'an SSL certificate' you mean a web server cert? Does it also have the 'for code signing' flag set?

Comment: @Rup: I have recieved a X.509-container with the private and public keyfile. I extracted both and afaik I can also use them for a web server.

Comment: OK, but it doesn't explicitly say 'Code Signing' or 'Microsoft Code Signing' in the X509v3 Extended Key Usage if you e.g. run it through `openssl x509 -text` or similar, or look at the properties in the Windows certificates MMC? I think the simplest thing would be to try it: sign a hello-world .exe, upload it to a web server then download it again and try to run the downloaded copy.

Comment: @Rup: I did not find a flag stating `Code Signing` - only various flags about `Digital Signatures` etc., but I will perform the test as you suggested and notify you about the results :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use SSL certificate to sign the code as it is intended for Server Authentication purposes only. You have to purchase a special code signing certificate that includes `Code Signing (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3)` entry in the Enhanced Key Usages extension.

Comment: I will do that, then. Thank you for your answer, Sir :)